# Batch File Recursive Search "File Not Found" error on Empty Folder

Tags: batch-file

When I run a recursive directory search for files it outputs "File Not Found" if the folder is empty but echo %count% is outputting 0 like it should.

```
setlocal
set /a count=0
for /F %%N in ('dir/s/b/aa "folder\name\*.txt"^| find /c "::"') do set count=%%N
echo %count%
```

All I want is a batch file to count the number of text files recursively in a directory and output the result like 999 and show 0 if the folder is empty. I have tried many variations of >nul and tons of batch search scripts. I am out of unvisited Google links to look at anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /F %%N in ('dir/s/b/a-d "folder\name\*.txt" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c ""') do set count=%%N
```

There should be a caret(`^`) before the `>` to escape the redirector.

Answer (score 1):

`File not found` is emitted to the standard error stream. You can silence that by redirecting it with `2>nul`:

```
for /F %%N in ('dir/s/b/aa "folder\name\*.txt" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c ""') do set count=%%N
```

Comment: This seemed like a good idea, but the one you gave me makes errors and crashes. "2> Was unexpected at this time"

Answer (score 1):

I know it is maybe not what you are looking at but have you tried:

```
dir/s/c folder\name\*.txt
```

I think it does almost exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This looks like almost exactly what I would of preferred to have lol. The only issue is it does not output plain numbers. Mine outputs a ton of information. Any idea on how to make it smaller? I added /b but then it output the full file name.

Comment: Which exact OS?  /c should just output the directory name and count - can't try it myself at the moment on windows/dos as I am on Linux.

Comment: Fair enough, I am on Win7 x64. http://imageshack.com/a/img163/5475/318c.png no big deal, I am going to look into it some more but yeah, not quite working.

Comment: Due to not wanting to spent a ton of time on this, I am just going to go with Joey's idea and Magoo's fix. But I appreciate it, it was very close to perfect if it had worked!